# BufferOverflow : ESP and access violation

Tags: exploit, exploit-development, x86

**The context :**

I have a small question regarding ESP and access violation.
I just exploited a buffer overflow, with little space after ESP.
So i did this :

part 1 : NOP SLED

part 2 : my shellcode : a shikata_ga_nai encoded reverse_tcp payload, by metasploit

part 3 : some more NOP to fill the space

part 4 : 4 bytes overwriting the EIP saved in the stack. This is the address of a jump ESP instruction in a non ASLS protected segment.

part 5 : [This is where ESP point to at the moment of the crash] I have some NOP

part 6 : the first stage of my exploit :

for the first stage, avoiding \x00 bytes, I did :

```
mov eax,esp
sub eax,944 (point to the part1 : the NOP sled)
jmp eax
```

It worked fine :
stack is overwritten, EIP goes to the jmp ESP instruction, arrives in the part 6 of the exploit, it jumps to EAX, wich point to the part 1 of the exploit, and then executes the NOP to arrive to the shellcode.

problem : I got some access violation inside the shikata_ga_nai decoder.

I solved it, adding a mov esp,eax in the first stage :

```
mov eax,esp
sub eax,944 (point to the part1 : the NOP sled)
mov esp,eax
jmp esp
```

And it worked like a charm.
So that would means one can not play with the memory in lower addresses than ESP.

**The question :**

Does ESP really has anything to do with read/write permission inside (outside actually) the stack ? The memory there was allocated, so I used it. Has EBP or other register anything to do with access violation ?

Comment: Stack grows towards zero... if you use classic buffer overflows you write to a base address + OFFSET meaning you can't touch anything that is on lower addresses than that buffer. Also, below ESP you might encounter unallocated memory which you can't just arbitrarily write to.

Comment: If you are using a str-family function to copy your data to the buffers, you might want to avoid other characters aswell besides \x00 (that I dont recall right now), since it could end the copying midway

Answer (score 0):

No, both registers just point to stack addresses, with ESP being the top of the stack and EBP the base of the stack frame (usually).